# Excel - Change column headers based on dropdown selection

Tags: excel

I am building a 12-month cash flow forecast and I want the user to be able to choose the start month from a dropdown. This will then change all the column headers. I have set up a dropdown, which now returns the month position in the built in array i.e. selecting Aug, returns month 8. What’s the best way to get 8=Aug?

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have full date (yyyy-mm-dd) you can format header to display month, by setting **mmm** non-standard format.
Also, you can define list of months and use CHOOSE() funcion, which returns given position from a list.
[Excel choose funcion](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/choose.php)